# Bootstrap Collapsed Menu should not take full width of screen when open

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, navbar

i am working on a web-app which uses navbar provided by bootstrap 3. The Nav bar is collapsed when we go to lower size screens. When the collapsed navbar gets opened the menu is taking full width of the screen. What i want to achieve is , when user opens the collapsed menu , the menu should only contain the width upto the max width of the content.
Example URL : https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=static-top-navbar

Please can you help me on this?